# How to get text from a datepicker

Tags: java, selenium

I need to get the pre-selected date in a datepicker. The problem I am facing is, when I click on the calender and I try to go into the datepicker table, it gets closed. Is there any way to get the prepresent text/date present in the date-picker. 
Below is the HTML code:

```
<div _ngcontent-c4="" class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control datepicker" id="violationEndDate" placeholder="Date Picker Here" type="text" _ngcontent-c3="">
      </div>
```

[image]

Comment: can you provide code example of automation and screenshot of the date-picker?

Comment: Have added the screenshot. And For automation script, I haven't written anything for that as I am not able to see the datepicker table structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following in C# :-

```
String currentDate = Driver.FindElement(By.Id("violationEndDate")).Text;
```

as i can see id is violationEndDate
you can also use xpath or cssSelector

```
String currentDate = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("*//input[@id='violationEndDate' 
and contains(@class, 'datepicker' )]")).Text;
```

I havent tested this as i dont have your Full HTML DOM code
Hope this will helpful